# Using relative path for a static image in a Jfree report template

Tags: tomcat, jfreereport

I have a JfreeReport Application which run under Tomcat inside a jar. In the report template (which exists outside the jar) I have the following:

  file:///var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/Reports/images/logo.gif
        
But then I get exception:
org.jfree.report.modules.ModuleInitializeException: Unable to create the specified directory.
Then I tried to use relative path but got FileNotFoundException.
I can't give a HTTP link for the file.
Any idea how to use relative path or file URL?

Answer (score 0):

How is your report requested. If it is resquest like

http://example.com/Reports/some-report

Then you need to use images/logo.gif

Answer (score 0):

A module initialized exception indicates a error during the booting/initializing of the reporting engine.

I'd say, you have a security manager installed, which blocks write-access to the home directory (the default location where the font-caches will be stored). Either reconfigure the location by setting the configuation properties

```
org.jfree.report.modules.misc.configstore.filesystem.SystemTargetDir=your/path/here
org.jfree.report.modules.misc.configstore.filesystem.UserTargetDir=your/path/here
```

to a location where you have write-access or disable the caching altogether (at the expense of a longer startup time, each time you restart Tomcat) by setting the config-property to an empty string (as shown below):

```
org.jfree.report.modules.misc.configstore.filesystem.Module=
```

The configuration can be set either by creating a "jfreereport.properties" file in the WEB-INF/classes directory or by setting the properties via System-properties (for instances in the Web.xml file).